# Why would proving:$f \in PRC \rightarrow g(y,x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{t=0}^yf(t,x_1,..,x_n)\in PRC$ by induction be wrong?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, computability

Let $PRC$ denote some primitive recursive closed class.

Why would proving: $f \in PRC \rightarrow g(y,x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{t=0}^yf(t,x_1,..,x_n)\in PRC$ by induction be wrong?

In the book "Computability, complexity, and languages", the following is stated:

> A common error is to attempt to prove this by using mathematical
>   induction on $y$. A little reflection reveals that such an argument by
>   induction shows that $g(0,x_1,...,x_n), g(1,x_1,...,x_n),...$
>   all belong to $PRC$, but not that the function $g(y, x_1 , \dots, x_n)$, one of whose
>   arguments is $y$, belongs to $PRC$.

Comment: Induction only shows that an infinite set of functions with fixed first argument are PR, but it says nothing about the function with varying first variable.

Comment: Isn't $g(y,...)$ just $g(1,...)$ if $y=1$, $g(2,...)$ if $y=2$,...,$g(n,...)$ for $y=n$? Looking at it that way it seems induction would be sufficient.

Comment: To define this function by cases, you would need an infinite number of cases, which isn't in general possible for PR functions.